# collection_select in ruby not allowing multi select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get a multi select dropdown working in Rails. The code is:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :tag_id %><br>
<td><%= f.collection_select(:tag_id, Tag.all, :id, :name, {:multiple => true})%></td>
```

I've also tried

```
<td><%= f.collection_select(:tag_id, Tag.all, :id, :name, :multiple true)%>
```

I thought that I should be able to hold the shift or ctrl and click on multiple items to select more than one item

I suspect that the problem could be in the schema for the documents table that is linked to the Tags model. .

```
  t.integer  "tag_id"
```

The documents model has

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
 . . .
   belongs_to :tag
  . . . 
end
```

and the tag model has has_many_documents

1. Does the multi actually work with f.collection_select
2. Should I be using something other than 'belongs_to :tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work

```
<%= f.collection_select(:tag_id, Tag.all, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple=> true})%>
```

You should pass it as the last argument(i.e, `html_options = {}`), but currently you are passing it in `options = {}`.